# All substrings of a string, without shuffling

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I've looked into Heap's algorithm for generating permutations, and all the numerous results on here for similar questions.

But they all seem to want every permutation where the input can be shuffled around as much as it wants to be.

I'd like a function that returns all possible substrings where the order remains the same so for input "abc" the result should not include "cba" for instance.

Here's what I mean:

`getAllSubstrings("abcdefg")` should return:

```
[
"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"
"ab","cd","ef",                   //"g"
"bc","de","fg",                   //"a"
"abc","def",                      //"g"
"bcd","efg",                      //"a"
"cde",                            //"fg", "ab"
"abcd",                           //"efg"
"bcde",                           //"a","fg"
"cdef",                           //"ab", "g"
"defg",                           //"abc"
"abcde",                          //"fg"
"bcdef",                          //"a""g"
"cdefg",                          //"ab"
"abcdefg"
]
```

Using `Set` to throw away the duplicate values is perfectly fine. I just can't wrap my head around how you would achieve the above. And it seems pretty simple...

Anyone got any good ideas for how one can achieve this?

Comment: why arrays with a single string?

Comment: So it's not a permutation, because permutations have fixed sizes but the order is swapped.

Comment: This is not what is meant with "all permutations". Seems you give the word a new meaning.

Comment: @trincot yeah I thought I might not be using the correct word as I wasn't finding anything other than what I described. Don't know what to call it otherwise though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you could do it with a generator:

```js
function* getAllSubstrings(s) {
    for (let len = 1; len <= s.length; len++) {
        for (let i = 0; i + len <= s.length; i++) {
            yield s.slice(i, i + len);
        }
    }
}

console.log(Array.from(getAllSubstrings("abcedfg")));
```

Or as a traditional function:

```js
function getAllSubstrings(s) {
    const result = [];
    for (let len = 1; len <= s.length; len++) {
        for (let i = 0; i + len <= s.length; i++) {
            result.push(s.slice(i, i + len));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(getAllSubstrings("abcedfg"));
```

Or in a functional style:

```js
const getAllSubstrings = s =>
    Array.from(s, (_, k) =>
        Array.from(s.slice(k), (_, i) =>
            s.slice(i, i + k + 1)
        )
    ).flat();

console.log(getAllSubstrings("abcedfg"));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I guess it's the nested i+len thing I couldn't wrap my head around.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach with a different oder of the result set.

```js
function* getAllSubstrings(s) {
    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) yield s.slice(0, i + 1);
    if (s.length === 1) return;
    yield* getAllSubstrings(s.slice(1));
}

console.log(Array.from(getAllSubstrings("abcedfg")));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that you have an off-by-one error somewhere, as none of your output strings include the final `"g"` from the input.